# Xcode 4.3.2 will not show full caller stack in debugger, only current function?

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging

Xcode 4.3.2 won't show me the caller stack for a Mac OS X application in the debugger. In the following image is the issue I am referring to, the stack only includes the current function:

[image: A single stack display]

The output of the stack should include the caller functions as such (taken from iOS that does not show the same debugging issue):

[image: Full stack display]

I have all the latest settings, the "validate build settings" runs without warning. I use pretty much the defaults as they come for a new project, here they are for my debug scheme:

- architecture = 32-bit Intel
- SDKROOT = macosx
- Debug Information = DWARF
- Deployment target = 10.5
- Strip debug symbols during copy = NO
- LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = @loader_path/../Frameworks
- ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO
- Optimization level = None
- Symbols hidden by default = NO
- Garbage collection = required
- GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES
- GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = MyHeader_Prefix.h
- WARNING_CFLAGS = -Wmost -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-unknown-pragmas
- IBC_WARNINGS = NO
- IBC_Strip_nibs = NO

Using a different debugger under "Edit Schemes", GDB over LLDB has the same issue. Switching compilers to LLVM also has no effect.

Clearing the derived data and cleaning the project has not helped. Also removing the pre-compiled information from /var/folders/ has proved unsuccessful.

It's a complicated question I just wanted to find out if anybody out there had a similar experience and was able to fix it. As it has worked for years and only recently stopped working.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can adjust the level of detail of the call stack display.

Look at the bottom side of the Debug Navigator :)

[image: Xcode 4.3.2 Debug Navigator]

Comment: Thank you. A setting I never knew existed. Simple things are the ones that are easy to miss.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post but I was having the same issue with Xcode 7.2.1. It turns out I had some old text in the filter search bar at the bottom of the pane. Once I cleared that out it works as expected.

At least I learned some lldb commands along the way.